# Access denied while running Mysql for the first time on Centos

Tags: mysql, centos, root

I just installed Mysql for the first time on a CentOS machine using `yum`. The installation had no errors. Then I followed those steps:

```
$ sudo /sbin/service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

$ sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!


In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
```

It can be seen that even after first installation there is issue in logging in to the DB. I have even tried all command in `sudo`, but the error is still there. I can't even figure out how to reconfigure MySQL. I halso have installed-removed mysql 3 times.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if it's the very first time you started up mysql, you shouldn't have run it yourself. the secure install script should start it for you...

Comment: It is asking for your password for the "root" account.  You need to enter it in instead of leaving it blank

Comment: I actually presses `enter` for the password

Comment: Yes, and the error states that is the wrong password.  You need to type it in before you press enter

Comment: What does one mean by "password being blank"? Is it pressing enter or entering some character?

Comment: @MarcB You mean I should not use `sudo /sbin/service mysqld start` and directly should run `mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: Password being blank means just pressing enter.

Comment: @FernandoGarcia is correct. You need to type in the characters for your "root" password before you press enter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you already setted it at some point. You can try this:

```
yum remove mysql-server
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
yum install mysql-server
systemctl start mysqld.service
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Anyway, I think this question should be in ServerFault.

Comment: `systemctl` is not on my system. I checked and it is a Centos 7's feature. I am using Centos 6. Can I use `/sbin/service mysqld start`?

Comment: Then start the service as you did before but make sure that you delete /var/lib/mysql

Comment: This did the job. `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql` was the thing that made this possible. Thanks!

Comment: This is an overkill, please see SubRed answer below

Answer (score 32):

Just for anyone who has this issue on MySQL 5.7. or higher.

MySQL v 5.7 or higher generates a temporary random password after installation and stored that in mysql error log file, located at `/var/log/mysqld.log` 
for an installation by the MySQL Yum repository on CentOS 7.

use below command to see the password:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Ref: [MySQL 5.7.7 - Centos 7 el7 - Access denied](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-5-7-7-centos-7-el7-access-denied)

**EDIT1**

For anyone that has different error log file, you can find it using @Drew's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289151/1846533) below.

Comment: Bullseye! I tried Fernando's solution which did not work for me but this one did it! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for a few hours looking for an answer, I have even reinstalled the whole OS because I thought I accidentally set a false password...

Comment: Thank you, this answer should be accepted as the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

A visual of the temporary root password written to the Error Log file

[image]

Not that one can exactly rifle off the command

```
select @@log_error;
```

to find the location of the Error Log file without logging in (a which came first, the chicken or the egg predicament).

But the typical locations are

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\
```

(for Windows. You must unhide the C:\ProgramData dir)

and

```
mysql> select @@log_error;
+---------------------+
| @@log_error         |
+---------------------+
| /var/log/mysqld.log |
+---------------------+
```

(for Linux)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo mysql_secure_installation`
2. When it asks for password type `pass`
3. Follow the prompts to change the root password

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstood. Because of you havn't set the password yet. you should just 
enter for none.

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.